# How to create floating image transition with css and react

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to create a floating image transition with CSS and react,same like in Divi theme header images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqNxz.png)

https://divisupreme.com/features/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.floating {
  -webkit-animation: movebounce 5s linear infinite;
  animation: movebounce 5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes movebounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes movebounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```
<div className='floating'><img src='YOUR_IMG' alt='' /></div>
```

Comment: What values you have added in movebounce ?

Comment: @UsamaLiaqat there you go.